# FirebaseMessaging callbacks (onMessage, onResume, onLaunch) are not getting invoked only for physical iOS device

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on version 6.0.16 (Latest), push notification working as expected in both android and iOS simulators, in foreground and background, but in the real iOS device, I just receive the notification in notification tray if the app is terminated or in the background, but I can't catch the click action or execute on message logic.

```
Here's my flutter doctor summary

[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.21.0-10.0.pre.55, on Mac OS X 10.15.6 19G73, locale en-EG)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.5)
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- click_action has to be set to "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"

2- click_action has to be set in the data section of a payload

```
 DATA='{
 "notification": {
 "body": "this is a body",
"title": "this is a title"
"click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
 },
"data": {
  "sound": "default", 
  "status": "done",
  "screen": "screenA",
},
"to": "<FCM TOKEN>"
}'
```

Comment: it has to be set in data section or notification section?

Comment: its in notifcation section because this is  "notification" key in data,If you confused let me know.

Comment: I get it in this section 
"data": {
  "sound": "default", 
  "status": "done",
  "screen": "screenA",
},

Comment: Also I successuffly handle the notification click in android, and onMessage is invoked while testing on the emulator!