# Firebase messaging onMessageOpenedApp

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending notification with firebase, when click on notification I want to redirect to a page in webview, how can I do that?

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessagemessage) {


   Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => ,
       ));

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63395409/20447561) here. The `click_action` payload should help your use case.

Comment: my question is, i am using webview, i want to redirect to a page from webview when notification is clicked

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    webviewcontroller.loadUrl(message.[urllocation]); 
});
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?